# Iperf tests in reverse direction

Tags: networking, tcp, iperf

I used iperf to measure the max throughput for TCP connection between two ubuntu machines. Both the machines were directly connected be means of a 1Gbps cable. When I performed iperf tests i obtained a bandwidth of 845 Mbps on an average. But when i tried reversing the direction (i.e changed server to client and viceversa) the results went down to 185 Mbps.These results are an average of ten readings and the max i was able to obtain was 370Mbps. I then decided to set the same value for parameters such as rmem_max, wmem_max, tcp_rmem, tcp_wmem but even after setting same parameters i got similiar results. i.e(845Mbps in one direction and 185Mbps in the other direction). I don't know what the possible cause could be. Is there something important that i have missed?

Comment: I just made a similar observation: In a similar setup, `iperf -c ...` is much faster for me compared to `iperf -r -c ...`. I have no explanation for this behavior either.